# Unable to get the UIFont for Chalkboard SE bold

Tags: ios, uifont

I can set all the fonts but when I try to set a style the compiler unwraps nil. I am building for iOS 9. These are the combinations I have tried:

```
    UIFont(name: "Chalkboard SE-bold", size: 18)!
    UIFont(name: "Chalkboard SE-Bold", size: 18)!
    UIFont(name: "Chalkboard SE bold", size: 18)!
    UIFont(name: "Chalkboard SE Bold", size: 18)!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "ChalkboardSE-Bold", size: 18)!]
```

Comment: UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "ChalkboardSE Bold", size: 18)!
        ]

Comment: font name is "ChalkboardSE-Bold" not like you specified .. you can check all available font namings here: http://iosfonts.com/